# Reading orc/parquet files from hdfs in spark

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, hdfs

I have a doubt while loading data into spark cluster(standalone mode) from hdfs say parquet or orc file whether it will just read the meta data or the entire data at the first instance. If I apply filter whether it will load the entire data and apply filter to it or it reads only the selected column and whether the entire data will be copied to spark if so where it will be present ...

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you mean by filtering but generally speaking, when accessing columnar structured files like Parquet or ORC, if you select specific columns you will only read them to memory and not the other columns.

Specifically if you are asking for something like ds.filter("..."), the ability to only read to memory the data that answers the filter is called "Predicate pushdown". generally speaking it is available in Spark but depends on exactly what you are trying to do. for example AFAIA, Spark can't do predicate pushdown on complex typed columns in Parquet files.

So I would suggest if possible only selecting relevant columns and then filtering. if you use complex types or spark SQL check on Google if predicate pushdown is supported.

Also, it doesn't matter if files are on HDFS or somewhere else like S3, behaviour should be the same

Comment: Thanks ... I can't  understand how spark has control in HDFS for selecting particular columns or filtering particular records in the file as I am using spark and HDFS in separate clusters and I am not using YARN as cluster manager in spark

Comment: selecting specific columns is a feature of Parquet format (and other similar formats such as ORC). you can read about it here: http://www.svds.com/dataformats/. Spark does not "have control" in HDFS. it reads/write from it.. think about it like storage machine. Yarn is also irrelevant.. it is in charge of resource management (applications, cpu, memory) and does not deal with storage.

Answer (score 0):

> If I apply filter whether it will load the entire data and apply filter to it or it reads only..

Spark doesn't load data into memory when filter transformation is done, it will not load data from the file till any **action** is done on it. This is because of lazy evaluation.

Comment: that is correct but I don't think that was what he asked about.. I assume he wants to do something with the filtered data but was concerned about performance.